# vue-loader is not importing components in webpack4 vue production mode

Tags: webpack, vue.js, webpack-4, vue-loader, ts-loader

**Update:** I was unable to find solution for this problem and I moved to vue cli 3.

I have typescript, vue, vuex and vue-router app and everything works perfect in development mode. Here are some vue and webpack versions:

```
"webpack": "^4.12.0",
"webpack-dev-middleware": "^3.1.3",
"webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.12.2",
"vue": "2.4.1",
"vue-router": "^3.0.1",
"vuex": "^3.0.1",
"vue-loader": "^15.2.1",
"ts-loader": "^4.4.0",
```

I am using `yarn run dev` to run the command and on `./src/main.ts` file I have imported a component and trying to console it:

```
import Master from './app/master/Master.vue'
console.log(Master)
```

The `Master` component is working fine in the development and in the production version the component is a empty object and I think `vue-loader` is not unable to import the component correctly.

```
`{}`
```

I have tried to use older versions of vue-loader but there some errors. The app is working on development here are my webpack configuration files listed from gist.

1. Build Configuration: https://gist.github.com/iksdatoo/492099d8147e8f60ee04b243426b799a
2. Base configuration: https://gist.github.com/iksdatoo/f9eda2bb81bc175cc59dac3879df2f28
3. Development configuration: https://gist.github.com/iksdatoo/522516c761b3422e7a1b5eafd0211bd8
4. Production configuration: https://gist.github.com/iksdatoo/5772a0517daf7463b98705396a1ce976
5. Package JSON File: https://gist.github.com/iksdatoo/a6883bddb37150dea00c22751e9aca06
6. Here is my entry point file: https://gist.github.com/iksdatoo/2d5f16159060a2d9d4cd8f7e02f984d7

Let me know what I am missing.

Comment: Anybody has the solution?

Comment: this is hard to debug without being able to replicate the issue.  Webpack config is hard to read for everyone. You might as well push a safe version of your project to a public git repo so that people are able to replicate the issue easily and help with debugging.

Comment: I will wait for some other guys to respond! othewise I will delete question!

Comment: Have you found a solution yet?

Comment: @MarziehBahri I had to go with Vue Cli 3 version which includes type script and all other platforms. There were some problems initially and now app is up and running with vue cli version 3.